# Execute shell script for database backup

Tags: cron

I have a ReactJS-neo4j application, deployed on a cloud server. Currently, i create backups of my databases manually.

Now I want to automate this process. I want to **automatically execute the above query every day**

Can anyone tell me how to automate the above process ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change your neo4j configuration file found in <HOME_neo4j>/conf/neo4j.conf as below. The location of the file is different if you are not using Linux server, like Debian.

```
apoc.export.file.enabled=true
apoc.import.file.use_neo4j_config=false
```

The 2nd line will enable you to save the json file from default folder "import" to any folder you want.

Then open a terminal (or ssh) that connects to your cloud server. Go to <HOME_neo4j> directory where cypher-shell is installed. Copy and run this one liner script below.

```
echo "CALL apoc.export.json.all(\"/home/backups/deploymentName/backup_mydeployment.json\", { useTypes: true } )" | bin/cypher-shell -u neo4j -p <awesome_psw> --format plain
```

This will save the json file in /home/backups/deploymentName just like what you do in your neo4j browser.

I will leave it up to you on 1) how to add the timestamp YYMMDD0000_ in the filename via linux command and 2) schedule the job every midnight via crontab. Goodluck!

Comment: thank you for your reply. I edited the question., tried to create a cron file like above. But it's not working. can you please have a look ?

Comment: Partially solved